# Get a radius of a circle in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a script to find radius of a circle and then find the area while the circumference is given

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the circumference: "
read CIRC
 PI=3.14
let RAD=$(($CIRC/((2*$PI )) )) 
let  AREA=$PI * $RAD * $RAD
echo "The area of a circle is: "$AREA""
```

The formula is:
    RADIUS=CIRCUMFERENCE/(2 * PI)
The problem is I cant make this formula work because bash doesn't accept decimal division
I read a lot of answers there but still can't get what I want

I have something like

```
let RAD=$(($CIRC/((2*$PI )) ))
```

was trying a lot of different variants,used bc -l
but still can't do it right and there are always a mistakes

Comment: Anything working here? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Comment: _"used `bc -l` but still can't do it right"_  Show what problem you were having with `bc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo -n "Enter the circumference: "
read CIRC
PI=3.14
RAD=`bc -l <<< "$CIRC/(2*$PI)"`
echo $RAD
AREA=`bc  -l <<< "$PI*$RAD*$RAD"`
echo "The area of a circle is: "$AREA""
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the circumference: "
read CIRC

PI=3.14
RAD=$(echo $CIRC \/ \(2\*$PI\)| bc -l)
AREA=$(echo $PI \* $RAD \* $RAD| bc -l)

echo "The area of a circle is: "$AREA""
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution with `awk`;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the circumference: "
read CIRC
awk -v CIRC=$CIRC " BEGIN { PI=3.14; RAD=CIRC/(2*PI); AREA=PI*RAD*RAD; print \"The area of a circle is: \",AREA}"
```